# React Router with Slugs - Link Not Working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm struggling to find documentation/solutions for this.

I'm setting up my react-router as follows:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
        <Route name="filterBy" path="/by/:category/:type" component={ProductListingContainer} />
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

and I'm trying to implement a `Link` as follows:

```
<li><Link to={'/by/format/vinyl'}>Vinyl</Link></li>
```

such that the Link path fulfills the slugs for the route. However it's not working. I'm guessing I'm getting the syntax wrong - any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: The error I'm getting:

> Uncaught Error: '<'Link'>'s rendered outside of a router context cannot navigate.

Comment: Try this `<li><Link to='by/format/vinyl'>Vinyl</Link></li>`

Comment: Still throwing an error :(

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] ? May be a fiddle?

Comment: In which component you are using this `<li><Link to={'/by/format/vinyl'}>Vinyl</Link></li>`?